# Tensorflow fails to load RNN from checkpoint after update

Tags: python, tensorflow

After updating tensorflow to the latest version, my checkpoint fails to load from disk. I get an error that looks like this:

```
...
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1560, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key model/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: model/save/RestoreV2_4 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_arg_model/save/Const_0_0, model/save/RestoreV2_4/tensor_names, model/save/RestoreV2_4/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable names have changed and they need to be renamed in the checkpoint. In the example above, `weights -> kernel`

Thankfully, someone has put together [a script which should automatically rename your variables](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/tools/checkpoint_convert.py). This not the first time variables have been renamed and broken loading from checkpoints.

```
usage: checkpoint_convert.py [-h] [--write_v1_checkpoint]
                             checkpoint_from_path checkpoint_to_path

positional arguments:
  checkpoint_from_path  Path to source checkpoint to be read in.
  checkpoint_to_path    Path to checkpoint to be written out.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --write_v1_checkpoint
                        Write v1 checkpoint
```